# Convert string 12 to year 2012 in excel

Tags: excel, date

My excel spreadsheet:

Col A
12
14
09

I want to convert column A into yyyy format as follows:

Col B
2012
2014
2009

Comment: Why not just add 2000?

Comment: I have to use yyyy for future date calculations. I want to convert string to year in a way that it becomes year 2012, 2014 etc.

Comment: Then you need to convert it to any day in that year and format it as desired.

Comment: Okay. I will try and post answer if got lucky. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXT("JAN 12", "YYYY")
```

This Will give 2012. 
To make it use for the data in  cell A1

```
=TEXT(CONCAT("JAN  ",A1), "YYYY")
```

Comment: But, as stated before, and this is just an FYI for the OP, this will return the four digit year and is essentially the same as `=A1 + 2000`

Comment: If you try 64 with the formula, (Text("Jan 64","YYYY") It will return 1964. With A1+2000, it will return 2064.